# Executing method from loaded nib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am new in ios development and currently i am having a problem trying to execute a method from a loaded class.

HERE IS THE SCENARIO

I have a class named "TV_kid", TV_kid will load another class named "Cable_kid" that contain a nib file.

That part is not the problem, the issues is that I now need to execute  a method using a button on the Cable_kid nib once TV_kid load it.

I though that it would be as simple connecting  and coding the method in the .h/.m files of the Cable_kid class but i keep getting this error  "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=2, address=0x18)"
without more details.

any idea or suggestion

This is how i am loading the Cable_kid class into a scrollview on TV_Kid

Note: loadSection is just a plist with a number of item

```
    id temp;
    int i=0;

    for(temp in loadSection){

       Cable_kid *cableKid = [[Cable_kid alloc]init];

       [TV_kid_container addSubview:cableKid.view];


  }
```

this will load a number of panel into the TV_kid Contanier with the Cable_kid nib class and functionality...but the problem is that the buttons of the loaded panels don't execute the method connected on the Cable_kid class...how can i execute a method once the panels load???

UPDATE

Here is a coded sample project that illustrate my actual problem

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20030125/SubViewMethod.zip

Comment: Show the code that loads `Cable_kid`.  (Should I assume that `Cable_kid` and `TV_kid` are both view controllers?)

Comment: Thanks for your interest Phillis...i have updated my question..hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this at all:

```
[TV_kid_container addSubview:cableKid.view];
```

Either put that view inside `TV_kid_container`'s view in the first place as a subview or turn `TV_kid_container` into a **real** container view controller by using the parent/child controller methods in `UIViewController`.  (E.g. `addChildViewController:`.)

Apple has a good video on this from the 2011 WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#implementing-uiviewcontroller-containment

Comment: was not the answer that i was looking for....but you mentioned a nice point that help the to avoid the use of UIViewController as subviews

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `Cable_kit`'s view has been initialised.

Use [`initWithNibName:bundle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) instead of `init`

```
Cable_kid *cableKid = [[Cable_kid alloc] initWithNibName:name bundle:bundle];

[TV_kid_container addSubview:cableKid.view];
```

Or [`- (void)loadView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/loadView)

```
Cable_kid *cableKid = [[Cable_kid alloc] init];
[cableKid loadView];

[TV_kid_container addSubview:cableKid.view];
```

Comment: Hi Michael...everything is loading PERFECTLY...I initialized the nib on the master class with super init...the problem is when the class is loaded and i click on the any of the buttons of the panels loaded it does not execute the method...it give the error stated before...keep in mind that i am loading multiples panels into an scrollView...Thanks!